# Does the US Army move tanks in bulk to Ukraine?

Tags: war, ukraine, army

I know the site I am sharing is mostly fake news. For instance their latest claim (excerpt below) is not supported by any link to external source. But still, the claim was really alarming and I am not sure how to fact-check it.

> The video shows "Dark train" not listed in any official route plans, full of American tanks M1A2 Abrams. These tanks are being routed through Slovakia to Ukraine

Source [AE News](https://translate.google.cz/translate?sl=cs&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=cs&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Faeronet.cz%2Fnews%2Fexkluzivne-nejnovejsi-zabery-nocniho-vlaku-ze-slovenska-ktery-veze-americke-tanky-m1a2-abrams-a-transportery-bradley-z-ceske-republiky-na-ukrajinu-valka-s-ruskem-se-blizi-milovymi-kroky%2F%3Ffbclid%3DIwAR3uZid5O2BxHfWOTO52tlQpn1iXiQosO5ihSd0s8Boul-FcJ2fqsyIGPgs&edit-text=&act=url) (link goes to machine translation from Czech to English) (5 Oct 2018)

Direct link to [video on Vimeo](https://vimeo.com/293462756)

Comment: Don't have time to write up an answer, but the pictures provided in that article have been harvested from other news articles about "Operation Atlantic Resolve", which is a very publicly known training operation in Estonia and Poland, and the photos are years old.  I can't speak to the video, but the images are not recent, some of them being from 2015.

Comment: The reason this is being closed is that sites which are "mostly fake news" (meaning "almost always tell lies") are not considered notable. The site doesn't waste time fact checking statements by people who are known to tell lies almost always. If you can find an actual notable claim for this then it can be reopened.

Comment: [Ukraine to export its newest Oplot tank to U.S.](https://www.uawire.org/media-informed-of-export-of-ukrainian-oplot-tank-to-u-s)

Comment: @DJClayworth Unless the well known habitual liar is too notable to be ignored because of the position he holds.